# How to handle invalid value: valid value range is empty using ? operator

Tags: dart

```
var items = [];
var index = 0;
var value = items[index]; // returns invalid value error, understood!
```

I should rather use following to prevent the error

```
if (index < items.length) {
  value = items[index];
}
```

Since there are `?` operators in Dart, I wanted to know is there any way I can do something like:

```
var value = items?.[0] ?? -1; 
var value = items?[0] ?? -1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `?` is used to for *null*-aware operators (or for the ternary operator).  Accessing an invalid element of a `List` throws an exception instead of returning null, so null-aware operators won't help you.

If you like, you could add a helper function and make it more convenient as an extension:

```dart
extension ListGet<E> on List<E> {
  E? get(int index, [E? defaultValue]) =>
      (0 <= index && index < this.length) ? this[index] : defaultValue;
}
```

and now you should be able to do

```dart
var value = items.get(0, -1);
```